# vbaでcsvのデータをエクセルに張り付ける

Tags: vba

vbaやマクロでファイル内にあるすべてのcsvファイルの特定の1列を検索して、先頭の4桁の数字で一致した行をすべて抜き出して別のExcelファイルに先頭の4桁と同じシート名に張り付けるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: この辺の記事や関連する事項を検索・学習・試行錯誤してみてください。[ＣＳＶからデータを選んで取り込む](http://www.start-macro.com/55/w/l197.html), [【超簡単】エクセルVBAでCSVファイルを読み込むマクロ](https://www.excelspeedup.com/readcsv/), [マクロ（Excel VBA）で CSV ファイルを開いてシートの中に取り込む方法](https://my-tax-nology.com/import-csv-data-to-excel-by-using-excel-vba)

Comment: ちょっと落ち着きましょう。「csvファイルの特定の1列を検索」というのは具体的に何のデータに基づいて行うのですか？　その後で、「一致した行をすべて抜き出して」の方は何に対して、どんな方法で行うのですか？　シート名に言及していますが、シートは最初からExcelファイルに存在してるのですか？　「ファイル内にあるすべてのcsvファイル」って、一つのファイルの中に複数のCSVファイルが入っている事はないですよ。　ちょっと落ち着いて、頭の中を整理しては如何ですか？